Absolute path removal when #cgo is used
I am working with an existing go code that uses #cgo parts. I am trying to make this code compile in a reproducible way in terms of the output binary (the same sha256/ md5 no matter in what dir it is built).
I fail to do this with the -trimpath argument, which works for non #cgo containing go code. I tried with -ffile-prefix-map for c code, but it does not seem to work as well. Here I tried to create a minimum working example that shows the issue. Used files:
main.go
package main

/*
#include "example.h" 

void helloFromC(); 
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Calling C function from Go...")
    C.helloFromC() 
}

example.h
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

void helloFromC(); 

#endif // EXAMPLE_H

example.c
#include <stdio.h>

void helloFromC() {
    printf("Hello from C!\n");
}

Makefile
export GOFLAGS = -trimpath -ldflags=-s -ldflags=-w -buildvcs=false
export CGO_CFLAGS = -ffile-prefix-map=$(PWD)=. -I. -O2

.PHONY: all build

all: build

build:
    go build -v -o gotest && md5sum gotest

go.mod
module gotest

go 1.22.3

In one dir:
gotest$ make
go build -v -o gotest && md5sum gotest
f9331174ca3b80fe3f616106a3871173  gotest

In another (link to the same dir):
gotest1$ make
go build -v -o gotest && md5sum gotest
e704e213e9d10b2846f29f20af9a3bf3  gotest

Furthermore, I have noticed that changing the h/c files in a non invasive way (i.e., adding white spaces or comments) influences the output binary md5.
What am I missing here?

When you run go tool objdump on the resulting binaries, does it list full or at least different pathnames for parts of the code it dumps?

The 2 dumps are identical when compared with diff...

Do runs of go version -m on the binaries produce identical results as well?

Łukasz, please tag the user you're responding to as @user, otherwise they won't get notified by SO; I've happened to have subscribed to your question so got one; otherwise I would have not.

@kostix Sorry, will mention now. The go version -m gotest produces the exact same output.

Do outputs of go tool buildid are the same?

@kostix no the outputs differ

May it be #59553 then?

@kostix it seems that this is exactly the case... Thank you. It seems that the issue is still not fixed in go 1.22.3

I'd recommend to chime in into the issue then.
